# Dolby claims to provide Spatial Audio under Interactivity API but no docs found regarding that

Tags: spatial, web-audio-api, dolby

I need to implement Spatial Audio specifically using Dolby's API.

In the [release notes](https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/reference/client-sdk/release-notes) it's clearly mentioned under `3.0.0` that "Spatial audio" experience is provided in `Dolby Voice` but in [Dolby Voice Guide](https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/guides/dolby-voice) they mentioned `Dolby Voice currently does not support spatial capture on any of the client platforms.`

I have also opened a ticket on Dolby Support but haven't got anything from there yet.

Any kinda help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: For Dolby Voice calls in the current 3.x release, spatial audio is an automatic distribution of the other talkers spanning between left and right, in order to separate their voices and make them easier to understand.

A future release will add an API giving the application control over the placement of each talker.

The quote from the guide is talking about spatial **capture** not output.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryMakin. I consulted Dolby support in this regard and they shared the same information as you mentioned in your comment ^.